# Setup my Windows server as a Proxy server for Iotawatt energy monitor

Tags: nginx, proxy, influxdb, influxdb-2, windows-server-2022

IotaWatt (IW) is an open source energy monitor with a lot of features and great perfomance. It is based on the ESP8266 chip and we have been using it for more than a year now. The monitor can send all the measured parameters to different Databases such as InfluxDB. Since the ESP cannot handle HTPPS requests, the monitor needs a proxy server to forward the HTTP request as a HTTPS request so it can upload the data to InfluxDB2 cloud. This is done with a Raspberry Pi with the following **nginx** script:

```
server {    listen 9000 default_server;     
            listen [::]:9000;

            root /var/www/html;     
            server_name _;

    

          location / {

        # Reject request without X-proxypass header         
        if ($http_X_proxypass = ""){            
            return 400;         }

        # DNS server to resolve dynamic proxypass URL       
        resolver 8.8.8.8;

        # Remove X-proxypass header         
        proxy_set_header X-proxypass "";

        # Send request to server        
        proxy_pass $http_x_proxypass$request_uri; 
        } 
}
```

My question is: how can I do something similar on Windows Server 2022?

I'm no expert on Windows server and what it ocurred to me was installing a virtual Linux server just to do this very thing, but I'm guessing that there could be an easier way to do this.

Thanks a lot!

Edit:

Thanks to @Crashtein for his answer.
I sure lack a lot of knowledge on Windows Server and the IIS and I ended up breaking the server several times, but I managed to get it to work via installing nginx for Windows and setting it up just as in the Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows Server it would be the best to configure proxy with IIS Server components. Process is more complicated than your configuration prepared for NGINX. If you lack of informations about Windows Server and IIS then I would recommend using Microsoft documentation to get familiar with basics, install components and configure it properly to rewrite your URLs with proxy on Windows.

This article should allow you to configure it properly in a way you want:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/configuring-application-request-routing-arr/creating-a-forward-proxy-using-application-request-routing